# Can my garden furniture be saved?

Tags: wood, furniture, gardening

I have some hand me down wooden furniture. Unfortunately, with multiple moves and births in the last few years, it has gone a unloved.

The wood seems very weak, and is brittle when dry. One beam snapped when stood on by a small child.

My question is, can I save it? I will obviously have to replace the broken beam, but can I treat it so that it doesn't become firewood?

Comment: Would it be possible to get a picture of it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the wood has already rotted or otherwise deteriorated beyond repair. If it is just a few pieces then you would need to replace those, but if the entire chair is rotted then it's likely destined for the scrap pile.

Generally speaking you need to finish the wood in order for it to hold up against the elements. Paint, shellac and varnish are some of the methods you could use.

Answer (score 1):

If people are going to get hurt you need to throw it away.  There is nothing to do that will save you time or money.